# Pointer related question in C inside a loop

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-management, casting

I am very new to C and having hard time understanding what the following lines of C code is doing.

```
for(j=0;j<np;j++)
    *(vt+i*np+j) = 0;
```

Before these lines assume i have defined the following:

```
int i=1,j,np=3;
double *vt;
vt=(double*)malloc(np*np*sizeof(double));
```

Also, I don't know what could be a good title for this question?

Comment: Is that whole code? Where is the declaration of `vt`? What is value of `i` ?

Comment: @VillageTech: Please see the edited question.

Comment: access of the 2d array

Comment: Why are you writing code that is difficult to read,?

Comment: please explain whats your problem exactly?

Comment: I am trying to understand line by line C code in a function (from a paper). What I am asking, is the small portion of the function.

Comment: @EdHeal: How do you know what code the OP is writing? The question contains only code they are asking about; it does not contain any indication they wrote it. (The supplementary note about “assume i have defined the following” is likely rhetorical, describing how `vt` is defined earlier in the code they are examining. Even if the OP had written those lines, it seems unlikely they would also have written the previously shown lines and then needed to ask about them.)

Comment: @EdHeal: And, in any case, debugging code is twice as hard as writing it (Kernighan), and therefore humans are doomed to forever struggle to interpret their own works.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Fair point that the code may be wrote by a third party. But the code presented IS hard to read - therefore problematic to debug/

Comment: @EdHeal: Hmm, something that is problematic. Where to go with problems, some place that one might present the problem and seek assistance?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - You can write code that is difficult to understand and parse, Or write code that is easier to understand and parse.

Comment: @EdHeal: Only up to a point. Humans continually seek to grow and do more. They exceed the easy things that have been done previously and push further. This is true both on a global scale and on the individual scale where students are pushing their own knowledge. Writing clear code is something that, for the most part, can only be done by somebody who is experienced and skilled and is writing something definitely within their comfort zone. It is a nice goal, but it is limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the author is trying to simulate a two-dimensional dynamic array with a one-dimensional array.

That is he allocated enough memory that could contain elements of a two-dimensional array of the kind

```
double vt[np][np];
```

and in loops like these

```
for ( i = 0; i < npl i++ )
{
    for( j=0; j < np; j++ )
    {
        *(vt+i*np+j) = 0;
    }
}
```

he is trying to fill this one-dimensional array with zeroes using two indices as if he is working with a two-dimensional array.

So this expression

```
*(vt+i*np+j)
```

is nothing more than dereferencing a pointer to get access to an element of a one-dimensional array using the pointer arithmetic.

Instead you could write for example

```
for ( i = 0; i < np * np; i++ ) vt[i] = 0;
```

where the expression `vt[i]` is equivalent to `*( vt + i )`.

To make it more clear here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void fill_array( double a[], size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            *( a + cols * i + j ) = cols * i + j;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;

    printf( "Enter the size of a square matrix: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    double *a = malloc( n * n * sizeof( double ) );

    fill_array( a, n, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%4.1f ", *( a + i *n + j ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
Enter the size of a square matrix: 5
 0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0 
 5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 
10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 
15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 
20.0 21.0 22.0 23.0 24.0
```

Comment: Is  *(vt+i*np+j) still a one dimensional array? Could you please give one simple example? I am very new to C.

Comment: I'm surprised that you can understand the real question without having outer loop.

Comment: @Hello vt is a pointer of the type double *. So it pointes to an element of a one-dimensional array. See my updated post.

Comment: @EsmaeelE It is because I am unemployed and have nothing to do.:)

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow: Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: One more question. Suppose, I want to fill a with x. x is 5 by 5 matrix. How can I do that?

Comment: @Hello You can use the same approach for one dimensional array that is calculating index of an element by eth expression i * cols + j while for the two-dimensional array us the expression x[i][j]